# Python's nonlocal keyword - is this good practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encapsulation

Consider a simple situation such as finding the k'th smallest element in a BST.

In my solution below:

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        i = 0
        ans = -1
        def traverse_inorder(root):
            nonlocal i
            nonlocal ans
            if not root:
                return
            traverse_inorder(root.left)
            i += 1
            if i == k:
                ans = root.val
                return
            traverse_inorder(root.right)
        traverse_inorder(root)
        return ans
```

Is my use of `nonlocal` for `i` and `ans` good practice? I do this to keep track of how many elements I've traversed after reaching the left most node (smallest value).

Another solution would be to have `i` and `ans` as member variables of the class:

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        self.i = 0
        self.ans = -1
        def traverse_inorder(root):
            # etc etc
```

Are both methods equivalent? Is one practice better than the other, and why?

Comment: Does it work? It seems well encapsulated, so I'd say it's fine. Making it a member of the class can allow others to modify it

Comment: Yeah it works. Hmm that's true, I think both variables (i in particular) wouldn't be relevant to other methods of the class so maybe the nonlocal approach is actually better in this case. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I've taken the liberty of moving your variable initializations into the `kthSmallest` method in the second solution. It would be very questionable design indeed not to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that under the circumstances you describe, the `nonlocal` approach objectively makes more sene than the other one you show. Your goal is to have a counter outside your function and a way to keep track of the result when it is found regardless of where you are in the recursion.

`nonlocal` completely encapsulates that information in a namespace dedicated to the particular run of your outer function. There is really no downside here.

Using instance attributes makes that information available to anyone using the instance. This is unnecessary conceptually, marginally slower, and not thread-safe. While thread safety is often not a concern in Python, it does make your code much less robust. Between that and encapsulation, I would definitely stay away from this approach.

I would suggest a third possibility here: using return values. In that case, your really don't need any external namespace. I don't necessarily recommend this over using `nonlocal`, but it's worth mentioning. Here is a sample implementation, which as you can see is much more verbose than your solution:

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        def traverse_inorder(root, target):
            if not root:
                return 0, None
            left_count, item = traverse_inorder(root.left, target)
            if left_count == target - 1:
                 return left_count + 1, root.val
            elif left_count < target:
                 right_count, item = traverse_inorder(root.right, target - left_count - 1)
                 return left_count + right_count + 1, item
            else:  # left_count == target
                 return left_count, item
        count, ans = traverse_inorder(root, k)
        if count < k:
            raise ValueError('Insufficient elements')
        return ans
```

There are many ways to do this with return values. Here, I compute the number of elements in each subtree, up to the target value. A non-none item is only returned if the exact number of elements is found.

Comment: Yep this is a good summary. Very good point about thread safety, and not one I had considered, thanks for that. 
The return option is one I initially considered before favouring the "cleaner" non-local approach. That being said, it's much more versatile and probably something to consider as a general practice. Thank you!